# Sqlite Row Number

Tags: sqlite

I have problem with my database row number. My table has 3 columns(ROWID,WORD,DEFINITION) and 3 row. I delete second row and then I try to query same row, my app fails. is this an autoincrement problem? what should I do?

Here is my code;
//Get that function

```
public String getThat(int id) { 
String result= "";  
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_WORD,KEY_DEFINITION};
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + 
"=" + id, null, null, null, null,null); 
if(c!=null){
c.moveToFirst();    
}   
result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION));

return result;
}
```

//delete function

```
 public boolean deleteRecords(long rowId){
    return ourDatabase.delete(DB_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +"="+rowId,null)>0;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

When the query doesn't match anything, a non-null `Cursor` is returned anyway but it doesn't contain any rows. When you try to access data from a non-existing row an exception is thrown.

Change this

```
if(c!=null){
c.moveToFirst();    
}   
result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION));
```

to something like

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION));    
}
```

i.e. check the return value of `moveTo..()` and only access cursor data if the move succeeded and the cursor points to a valid row.

Comment: nop, it doesnt work. I think my app has to decrease third ROWID to 2 after I delete the second row but I really dont know how to do it

Comment: Identifiers shouldn't really change once assigned. If a piece of code depends on identifiers being contiguous, fix that piece of code.